# Are workflows sensitive to data changes?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, date-time

I want to make a workflow that will move an item from one list to another once the current date exceeds the archive date.

I was wondering, do workflows just save the values they are given once they are started, or are the constantly querying the list object they act on so they can pick up changes?

For example, if I do a "pause until date" action and I set the value of the date to pause until to a field in the list item, if the item is updated, will it pause until the original date or the updated date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pause activity require to know how long it should Pause. So once it entered the Pause state it will wait till the time frame mentioned as part of initialization.

In your case if the date field changes you should start another workflow which basically kills the previous and start a new Pause activity based on the new date.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow will pause till the original date only but will run with the updated data.

Comment: I don't quite understand, how is it running with the updated data if it only pauses until the original date? The whole point of the date field is to say when to pause until, so if it doesn't stop on the updated date, it isn't really using the updated data.

Comment: When you check the state of the workflow when it is pausing ,it will show that it is pausing for __ minutes.Any step that comes after the pausing state will run with the updated data,as the workflow was pausing when the list was updated.